# How to ignore a second parameter in a variable declaration if only one is given

Tags: python

I wrote a function to carry out 4th order Runge Kutta, however, it only works if I input a function with two independent variables. I want to make the function capable of handling a function with only a single independent variable.

```
def RungeKutta(fun, x0, y0, h, end=None, n=None):
    x = x0
    y = y0
    
    if end == None:
        for i in range(n):
            k1 = fun(x, y)
            k2 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k1) / 2)
            k3 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k2) / 2)
            k4 = fun(x + h, y + h * k3)
            y = y + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

            x = x + h

    else:
        n = (end - x0) / h

        for i in range(n):
            k1 = fun(x, y)
            k2 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k1) / 2)
            k3 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k2) / 2)
            k4 = fun(x + h, y + h * k3)
            y = y + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

            x = x + h
   return y
```

I'm using the following equation and call:

```
A = 1250
Q = 450
WaterLevel = lambda t: ((3 * Q) / A) * mt.sin(t)**2 - (Q / A)
print(Rg(WaterLevel, 0, 0, .5, n=1))
```

So, for the given equation, the function call fails because the inputted equation is incapable of handling a second input and the function defines variables by calling the inputted function with two inputs. How can I create the equation so that it can also handle an equation that only takes one independent variable?

Comment: Can't you define your lambda function with 2 inputs anyway, even if the following call will only use the first of the two variable passed?

Comment: You should really get rid of that duplicate code block.

Comment: The amount of work it'd take to generalize the intermediate steps I don't think would be worth the effort. Why not just implement separate `runge_kutta_univariate` and `runge_kutta_multivariate` functions?

Comment: really: `n = (end / x0) / h` ??????

Comment: are you calculating a volume or a surface

Comment: Another implementation with Scipy.ode.integrate accepts a flat array so it can work with as few or as many inputs as the situation calls for.  That may be another approach to consider.  That way you dont have to modify the code for each arity of dx/dt you want to accept and can just rely on vector operations from numpy which would run faster too.

Comment: The second duplicate code block is to allow you to choose how you input your range, which is why the line of code for n = end - x0 / h is there, it calculates the number of iterations if you only input a start and end point. Or you could just put a start point and number of iterations and it runs the other block. @ddejohn

Comment: @ Mike Holcomb I’m aware scipy exists that could just do it for me, this is for a homework assignment and I have to write it myself. I don’t even need to accomplish this to finish the assignment, it’s just a question I had while doing it.

Comment: I understand that but that can be achieved simply by `n = ...` behind the if/else block. The for loop is identical in both blocks, which is unnecessary duplication.

Comment: Note also that if `n` is not provided in a call to this function, it will not work as `n` is only defined in one of the blocks and is `None` by default.

Comment: It does work If n isn’t provided (I’ve tested it), it runs the second code block and generates its own n value. Wouldn’t putting the “n=…” after the if else block make it fail? Since the n hadn’t been generated when it tries to call n? @ddejohn

Comment: If `n` and `end` are both left to default, your code will fail. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you have one optional parameter that may or may not be given, why not make it optional in your function call as well (`y0=None`)? Then the function can handle the different cases, e.g. by dispatching your values to different background implementations. (You'll need to reorder the parameters in the function call so that all positional arguments come first though.)

---

In general, if you want to have a function that you can call with any unspecified number of arguments, you can handle them using tuple packing in the function definition using the `*` operator. As an advanced example including mandatory and optional parameters:

```
def test(param1, param2, *args, opt1=None, opt2=None):
    print(param1, param2, args, opt1, opt2)
```

Then:

```
>>> test(1, 2)
1 2 () None None
>>> test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
1 2 (3, 4, 5) None None
>>> test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, opt1=True, opt2=False)
1 2 (3, 4, 5) True False
```

Again, you'll have to code a robust way to handle what happens when different numbers of arguments are given. And whether or not this is a good way to do things obviously depends on your use case. The built-in `print` function, for example, works very well this way. But if you know that there will always be a certain number of function arguments, making them optional in the function call would probably be the cleaner way.

Comment: This explains how I could go about accomplishing this. Is there a way to make the function detect how many variables the inputted equation requires?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... can you clarify?

Comment: I’m inputting a lambda function into this Runge Kutta function. Is there a way to make the Runge Kutta function able to tell how many variables the lambda function requires?

Comment: Oh, I see -- it's the `fun` parameter. If there are ways to determine the number of parameters that a function takes, it'll probably be something very hacky. I'd suggest to either code towards a number of implementations that need to be covered (if it's not too many); or, if you absolutely must abstract this out further, hand the number of variables over as another function parameter to the Runge-Kutta function.

Comment: Gotcha! That’s what I ended up doing actually, thank you!

Comment: You can use [inspection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) if you want to get into the weeds.

Answer (score 1):

### A hack to make your code work

```py
In [21]: import math

In [22]: A = 1250
    ...: Q = 450
    ...: WaterLevel = lambda *t: ((3 * Q) / A) * math.sin(t[0])**2 - (Q / A)

In [23]: print(RungeKutta(WaterLevel, 0, 0, .5, n=1))
None
```

Note that I've altered the lambda to accept an arbitrary number of arguments with `*t`, but only use the first, `t[0]`, in the actual function. Your code runs fine in this case. But again, your function doesn't actually return anything, hence the `None`.

### Clarifying my comments

Right now, your code has a logical error. It will raise a `TypeError` if both `n` and `end` are left to default in a call to `RungeKutta`:

```py
In [17]: RungeKutta(f, x0, y0, h)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ccd875a4d56f> in <module>
----> 1 RungeKutta(f, x0, y0, h)

<ipython-input-11-79bd92b0fca3> in RungeKutta(fun, x0, y0, h, end, n)
      4
      5     if end == None:
----> 6         for i in range(n):
      7             k1 = fun(x, y)
      8             k2 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k1) / 2)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

In terms of removing your duplicate code, the *only* difference between the two blocks of code in your `if`-`else` branch is `n = (end - x0) / h` in one of the branches. The `for` loop is identical in both branches, therefore it is redundant and should be moved outside of the branching statement entirely:

```py
def RungeKutta(fun, x0, y0, h, end=None, n=None):
    x = x0
    y = y0
    
    if end is not None:
        n = (end - x0) / h

    for i in range(n):
        k1 = fun(x, y)
        k2 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k1) / 2)
        k3 = fun(x + h/2, y + (h * k2) / 2)
        k4 = fun(x + h, y + h * k3)
        y = y + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

        x = x + h
```

Note that the logical error is still present in the above snippet of code.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Yea I knew it would fail if you left both without an input, just kinda assumed that you would always input at least one of the two because that’s how Runge-Kutta works, I could put a check in the function that returns an error saying you have to input one of the two at the start to resolve that though.

Comment: That cleanup is a lot cleaner! I’ll do that, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've added a "solution", see my edit.

Comment: Thanks @ddejohn! I’ve edited my post to include the return, that was just an omission on my part